# Ruby convert a string which looks like utc format to a date

Tags: ruby, datetime

I have a string in the format of "2016-03-02T17:27:32.000+00:00", which I need to convert to a Time object. Is there an easy way in ruby to do this or do I need to parse the string first?

When I try

```
Time.new("2016-03-02T17:27:32.000+00:00")
```

I get

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 4):

Your time format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). To parse it, you can use [`Time::iso8601`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-iso8601):

```
require 'time'

Time.iso8601('2016-03-02T17:27:32.000+00:00')
#=> 2016-03-02 17:27:32 UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Time.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) to make a Time object out of a string:

Since `.parse` is defined in the standard library, not the `core` library you need to require the standard library with `require 'time'`:

```
require 'time'
Time.parse("2016-03-02T17:27:32.000+00:00")
=> 2016-03-02 17:27:32 +0000
```

Comment: I tried that - I get undefined method `parse' for Time:Class. I'm using ruby 2.1.7